# React-Native: Fetch delayed / slow when used in React-Navigation Stack Navigator

Tags: react-native

When I use fetch calls to my API within Screens that are Root screens in my tab navigator, they basically resolve immediately. Once I do the same calls (same code) within a pushed screen which was pushed onto one of the root screens then they are very slow. They are delayed by up to 20 seconds to resolve.

Tab Navigator: Screen A, B, C, D, E (All resolve fast)
All Stacked Navigators: Screens A.a, B.b, .... or A.a.a (Very slow)

Does anyone know how the navigation might impact the fetches?

Some Code.

This is how I do the fetch with a hardcoded ID for testing.

```js
getMessagesForConversation('5dd42e155a852e73757b35a4', 1, 0).then((res) => {
    res.json().then(response => {
        this.setState({
            messages: response.messages
        });
    })
```

This is how I connect to the websocket. When I remove that in both screens its much much faster.

```js
        this.socket = socketIO.connect(ENV.WS_SOCKET, {secure: true});
        this.socket.on('message' + '/' + '5dd42e155a852e73757b35a4', (message) => {
            this.setState({
                messages: [message.message].concat(this.state.messages)
            });
        });
```

This is my stack in the App.js I use for Navigation. Conversations are root, messages are the single chat screens.

```js
    const ChatStack = createStackNavigator(
    {
        ConversationsScreen: {
            screen: MessageScreen2,
        },
        MessageScreen: {
            screen: MessageScreen
        },
    }
```

Not much magic overall ... this is the navigation code.

```js
    this.props.navigation.navigate('NotificationScreen');
```

It's really when I remove sockets it works. But they connect successfully.

This is the fetch in detail.

```js
    export const getMessagesForConversation = async (conversationId, limit, page) => {
    return AsyncStorage.getItem('userJwtToken').then(token => {
        return fetch(ENV.API + 'chat/conversation/'+conversationId +'?page=' + page + '&limit=' + limit, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'x-auth-token': token,
            },
        }).then((resp) => {
            return resp
        })
    });
};
```

Comment: Can you share some code with us or mount a minimal project ?

Comment: I found out when I remove my socket.io-client connects in the root and stacked controller, it is much faster. But I need those connections :/

Comment: Maybe it is doing some long synchronous operations before calling the API ?

Comment: No, the weird thing is the fetch code is started, but it does take very long to resolve. Actually it takes very long that the request reaches my node server.

Comment: I also added the fetch code :) The "return fetch ..." is reached. But until "return resp" it takes quite some time and no request hits my api endpoint  :/

Comment: @user983814: I am facing this issue now. do you have any insights to share?